# CefSharp showing odd margins

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I've just been starting with CefSharp as an embeddable web browser, to replace the default WinForms webbrowser (by wrapping either in my own class).  (I didn't want to use the 'minimal example' that brings CefSharp in at the form level, as for this app I dynamically add the UI elements, and in general I'd like to be able to use the webbrowser without having the form be aware of it.

It "kind of works" in the simple example I've got, the website indeed appears, but there are black sections to the left and above the website shown, and a white block in the upper-left-hand corner.  These show up even if no URL is specified.  This may have to do with some setting or other, but I haven't been able to track it down.  I'll insert an image of what I'm seeing to be a bit clearer.  (If I use the Winforms Webbrowser I just see the google map in the control as I expect when I visit map.html, that is, there are no surrounding blocks).  I do have a number of reasons I'd like to move beyond that control in the future, and this feels quite close to working.

I just now noticed that when I mouse move into the white area in the upper left the icon changes, it looks like these regions have some mouse-click functionality, in which case I need to find out how to not have them appear.

The "Do it" button actually does the LoadURL; in the eventual app, the control will be hidden unless the EXIF data of a photo has the lat/lon data present.  So in this example I begin with CefSharp's ChromeWebbrowser with nothing loaded, then use the button to emulate that dynamic URL setting (there's code that writes the MAP.HTML file - I'll include that file too, for reference, though the problematic sections appear with no URL specified.)
[The environment is VB.net in Visual Studio 2022, on Windows 10]

[image]

So, for the code - I have a class file for MyWebBrowser, which is what I'll use on the form.  Initially it just inherited from the Winforms webbrowser control, but I've commented that out - I can go back and forth using either that of CefSharp via commenting out one or the other, just to test form-level issues and see that things are largely the same.  Not sure facilities VS has for conditional compilation, that's for another day.)  Anyway here is the code, captured as an image:
[image]

The invoking form dynamically creates a MyWebBrowser, then sets the URL when the button is clicked.  This is the form code:
[image]

This is what the form looks like before I load any URL:
[image]

FYI, here's the map.html file being displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
   <meta charset="windows-1252" >
   <TITLE>Map</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
<BODY>
<iframe
  width=300
  height=494
  frameborder="0" style="border:0" src=http://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed&q=41.4098277777778%2C-71.9060972222222>
</iframe>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport You need to make your application DPI aware. See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/102/NuGet/Readme.txt#L13

Comment: I will read those, but as I've had a 4K monitor for years and done dev on it, I *think* I've done all that's needed to manage the DPI aware issue.  I will revisit.  On amaitland's point, I think everything there has been done too, but will also revisit.  (What's odd here is that it "works", that is there are no errors, exceptions, missing references, or anything of that sort, it just appears strangely, with apparently functional rectangles (allowing mouseclicks, saw "Back" and "Forward" when testing), so it seems I have browser elements I should just be able to turn off.

Comment: Your application needs to be made DPI aware. Your system is almost certainly using a DPI greater than 100%. Whilst it may appear odd this is expected when there's a mismatch between system DPI awareness and application awareness when using CefSharp.

Comment: amaitland, I understand.  One issue that immediately comes to mind is that this system may go to others, so presumably this awareness will be in the code itself, not in some Visual Studio setting - that is, resolution might be quite different on other machines.  I'm going to assume that can be done and will delve into it.  BTW, when you say "this is expected", do those odd blocks I see have some known functionality?  Just curious.

Comment: amaitland, I set the dpi awareness in a (newly created) manifest file, and it works.  Many thanks.  Not sure how to mark your comment as the solution, but I'll give it a shot!

(Quick research says if you post that as an answer, I can mark it as such.  Maybe my comments are good enough, but happy to do that if you do whatever is needed, maybe just edit your post to make it an answer that I can confirm.)

[Also - not that I need to do it today - but many systems have multiple monitors, at different resolutions, so I'm not sure I've thoroughly fixed this problem, but for now it's fine.]

Comment: I've posted an answer, hopefully it will provide some clarity, if you are targeting .Net 4.7 or above you may wish to use the app.config based approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Desktop applications using WinForms/WPF need to be made DPI Aware to run correctly on a High DPI Display (A display with a DPI Scale set greater than 100%).

> Note If you mouse cursor is incorrectly positioned in the browser or the browser displays black boxes/border with rendering/resizing then your app needs to be made DPI Aware. Other parts of your application may also appear blurry or incorrectly-sized.

As per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport

The simplest resolution is to make your application DPI aware. There are a number of options to achieve this.

- If you are targeting .Net 4.7 or higher then using the guide available at [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is recommended.
- For older versions then [Configure via app.manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest)
- For .Net Core and .Net 5+ there is also a new progremattic method [Application.SetHighDpiMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest)

---

To address some of the questions in the comments:

1. The black blocks are a result of the browser process (Your application) having a mismatch in DPI awareness with the GPU compositor (by default CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe is used with --type=gpu-process). Both need to have the same DPI awareness. When they differ it's expected you will see black boxes.
2. Desktop applications must tell Windows if they support DPI scaling. By default, the system considers desktop applications DPI unaware and bitmap-stretches their windows. Once your application correctly supports DPI awareness then it'll work on systems that use the default DPI of 100% and those that use a higher DPI e.g. 200%

Anyone interested in learning more then I'd suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#display-scale-factor--dpi